# Обновление данных QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtableview

Столкнулся с проблемой не могу понять как заставить QTableView в pyqt5 отображать новые данные. Данные полностью меняются (**целиком**), после нажатия кнопки **Update**.
Подскажите правильный подход.

Удаление и вставка по одной строке не подойдет, строк за одно обновление порядка 3-10к.

Ниже указана часть кода

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QModelIndex

class TmodelCustom(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data=None, header=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.load_data(data)
        self.header = header

    def load_data(self, data):
        self.input_address = data[0]
        self.input_numbers = data[1]
        self.column_count = 2
        self.row_count = len(self.input_numbers)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.row_count

    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.column_count

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant(self.header[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        column = index.column()
        row = index.row()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if column == 0:
                return "{}".format(self.input_address[row])
            elif column == 1:
                return "{}".format(self.input_numbers[row])
        return None


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        header = ["ADDRESS", "NUMBER"]
        df = [['1', '2', '6'], ['3', '4', '5']]

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(grid_layout)
        self.model = TmodelCustom(data=df, header=header)

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)

        update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update")
        update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_update_button)
        horisontal_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        horisontal_layout.addStretch(1)
        horisontal_layout.addWidget(update_button)
        horisontal_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        grid_layout.addLayout(horisontal_layout, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0)

    def on_update_button(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Заранее благодарю Вас!

Comment: Вы пишите,что столкнулись с проблемой и не можете обновить `QTableView`. Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick О каком примере может идти речь(в качестве примера я могу показать только  как подключаю qtableview к диалоговому окну и все). Вопрос том как это сделать? По какому принципу это работает.

Comment: опубликуйте то что у вас есть и лучше расскажите, что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @S.Nick отредактировал. Если у вас найдется время. Буду очень признателен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сказать таблице, что данные в модели изменились. Делается это при помощи методов, которые объявлены в классе QAbstractItemModel и чье имя начинается с begin ("начинающие транзакцию") и парные  им end ("закрывающие транзакцию"), и/или сигнала [QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged).

В частности, в вашем случае, видимо, подходят пары функций [QAbstractItemModel.beginResetModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) и [QAbstractItemModel.endResetModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endResetModel).

```
def load_data(self, data):
    self.beginResetModel()
    self.input_address = data[0]
    self.input_numbers = data[1]
    self.column_count = 2
    self.row_count = len(self.input_numbers)
    self.endResetModel()
```

Теперь, соответствующий вызов функции обновления модели, с соответствующими аргументами должен обновить таблицу:

```
def on_update_button(self):
    self.model.load_data(...)
```

Comment: Было бы просто замечательно если бы вы показали пример с QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged. Но в любом случает это помогло. Очень благодарен.

Comment: @Edy не покажу, но суть в том, что вашим ячейкам/данным соответствуют QModelIndex, соответственно, когда вы меняете какие-либо данные в модели данных надо получить соответствующий интервал измененных QModelIndex и передать его в качестве аргумента dataChanged. Не ваш случай

Answer (score 2):

я предложу вариант с использованием модели `QStandardItemModel`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Counter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.setColumnCount(2)
        self.model.setRowCount(0)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['ADDRESS', 'NUMBER',])
        self.table.setModel(self.model)    

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Укажите количество строк:")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit("7")
        update_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Update")
        update_button.clicked.connect(self.on_update_button)

        self.iter = None
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=200, timeout=self.add_row)
        
        grid_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(central_widget)        
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        grid_layout.addWidget(update_button, 0, 3)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.table, 1, 0, 1, 4)
        
    def on_update_button(self):
        try:
            rows = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        except ValueError:
            print("Введенное значение должно быть целым числом.")
        else:
            if rows > 0:
                self.model.setRowCount(0)                           
                self.iter = iter(range(rows))
                self.add_row()
                self.timer.start()
            else:
                print("Введенное значение должно быть положительным целым числом.")

    def add_row(self):
        try:
            i = next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            self.iter = None
            self.timer.stop()
        else:
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem("item" + str(i))
            item1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem("item" + str(i))
            item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.model.appendRow([item1, item2])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = Counter()
    window.setWindowTitle("Counter")
    window.setMinimumSize(480, 380)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем подходит. Потому что добавляем построчно. Я хотел от этого как раз уйти. Но все равно спасибо.

Comment: @Edy уточните пожалуйста, суть вашего обновления. Как вы хотите делать обновление.

Comment: @ S.Nick Отдать функции данные целиком. И не думать о итерациях, который добавляют их по одной строчки (хотя где то внутри pyqt наверняка так и происходит). Основываясь на этой странице [ссылка](http://rsdn.org/forum/cpp.qt/5135089.flat) используя dataChanged или связку beginResetModel() и endResetModel() новая прорисовка данных должна работать быстрее. Ответ из базы, который потом использую для отображения довольно большой.

Comment: @Edy   мне показалось, что данный пост https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52609229/update-data-on-qt-qdatawidgetmapper-while-mapper-index-stay-unchanged как-то перекликается с вашим.

Comment: Да очень похож. Жаль что я не наткнулся на него ранее.